# How to store pow(10,n) integer values in c where n can be <200?

Tags: c, numbers, storage

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<math.h>     

int main(void)
{
    long int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n=pow(10,n);
    printf("%ld\n",n);
    solve(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use two variables, one for the input _(which should be typed `int`, not `long`, if you use `%d`)_, and another for the computed power-of-10 _(which should be typed `double`, and accordingly the `%g` specification)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `double`, not `long` (since 10<sup>80</sup> won't fit in a 64 bits `long` which can express numbers below [9223372036854775807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807)). But read [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/), since it is a very difficult subject (notice that [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers are not the same as mathematical [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)).

You might try:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>     

int main(void) {
  int n = 0;
  if (scanf("%d",&n)<1) { perror("scanf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  if (n < -256 || n > 256) 
    { fprintf(stderr, "wrong exponent %d\n", n);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  double x = pow(10.0,(double)n);
  printf("ten power %d is %g\n", n, x);
  return 0;
}
```

(I removed the call to `solve` which you did not define; I tested the success of `scanf` and the range of `n`)

For much larger exponents, you'll need [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) perhaps using [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling. If you compiled your original code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you'll be warned many times (nearly one warning per line!).